# I don't want use the Analyzer to do search, how can i do?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Lucene+Hibernate Search, and choose the DefualtAnalyzer as the Analyzer.
But I wouldn't like it, i just want the inputed value can be matched accurately.
For example ,input 'I love you' , it will be analyze as '[Ilo lov ove eyo you]'.

I just want I just want 'I love you' match 'I love you', if it isn't 'I love you' ,you cann't find out anything.

So how let it work?

Comment: Could you please refine your question. The default analyzer is called _StandardAnalyzer_. Your tokenization example does not make sense and to be honest I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: From the output I guess he's using an N-Grams Analyzer.

Comment: Yes,Sanne. But I don't want use any Analyzer. just anything can be matched accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
    Querybuilder builder=fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().
                           buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(persistentClass).get();
    Query luceneQuery=builder.keyword().
                        onField("fieldName").
                        ignoreAnalyzer().
                        matching(queryText).createQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to turn off analyzing during the indexing process you need to use:

```
@Field.analyze(Analyze.NO)
```

Comment: Here is my ORM class:@Analyzer(impl = DefaultIndexAnalyzer.class)    // Use a pre defined analyzer
public class RefAddressModel implements java.io.Serializable
{ ..}  how to disable the @Analyzer ? i don't want use any Analyzer while indexing and searching